# Jetty 6 Maven Plugin fails to start on Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm moving from Eclipse to Intellij, and switching from Tomcat to Jetty in the dev environment.
My Tomcat plugin works fine, but when I start Jetty it outputs the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.2:run (default-cli) on project projeto: Webapp source directory C:\Users\EvCash - Blue\workspace\projeto\src\main\webapp does not exist -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.2:run (default-cli) on project projeto: Webapp source directory C:\Users\EvCash - Blue\workspace\projeto\src\main\webapp does not exist
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

And the run configuration:

```
jetty:run -e
```

I tried using the jetty-runner plugin, but it requires JDK 1.8 and I must use the 1.7 version.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does "C:\Users\EvCash - Blue\workspace\projeto\src\main\webapp" really exists? If yes, maybe try to move to a directory without spaces inside its path.

Comment: Apparently that's the reason, there is a bug relatedto jetty and spaces in the path, like the one reported here https://github.com/openhab/openhab2-addons/issues/336

Comment: Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2009, consider upgrading to something supported / stable.

Comment: If you have a Java 1.7 requirement (incidentally, Java 1.7 is also EOL now too), then use Jetty 9.2.x series (which is supported and stable, for the time being)